# Send XML file over HTTP POST

Tags: http

I want to send a bunch of XML files from my client (iPad)  to my application server(Web)..Is there any way I can pass them to server using HTTP POST? I assume HTTP POST only allows embedding strings not attaching as files..We don't want to use FTP due to securuty reasons. We even thought of web service, but not sure whether attachments are possible..Pleas advise if you know any ways of transferring files from client to server.

Comment: What technologies do you want to use? Native App, HTML/JavaScript?

Comment: From native app (objective C), I want to call HTTP POST to transfer some files (Zipped XML Files) to the server..

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of a POST variable is massive - so no worries there, you can send XML fine.  POST can send any type of data, just make sure you set the Content-Type header correctly or you may get unexpected results.

It is no less / more secure than FTP however.

Comment: Thanks edmond..Is FTP upload really faster than HTTP POST for file transfer?

Comment: FTP is a specific protocol for transferring files whereas HTTP POST is more suited to form data, so it's likely to be faster although I'm no expert.  If you like the answer you should vote up and/or accept as answer.

Comment: Ok..Can I transfer some ZIP files (can contain anything) over HTTP POST?